# How to implement the interface and initialize the object like java in JRuby?

Tags: java, ruby, interface, jruby

I don't know how to initialize the interface object with the JAVA class in JRuby.

In the below code **OAuthService is the Interface** and **ServiceBuilder is the Class**

Java ::

```
OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
System.out.println(">>>>>>>" + service.getClass());
Output >> class org.scribe.oauth.OAuth20ServiceImpl
```

But in JRuby I don't know where to write OAuthService interface to initialize the object.

JRuby ::

```
service = ServiceBuilder.new()
puts service.java_class
Output >> class org.scribe.builder.ServiceBuilder
```

The below code executes and works perfectly when I execute in JAVA

```
      OAuthService service = ServiceBuilder.new()
                                  .provider(FacebookApi.class)
                                  .apiKey(apiKey)
                                  .apiSecret(apiSecret)
                                  .callback("http://localhost:3000/oauth_callback/")
                                  .build()
```

But in Ruby it give error

Error ::

```
irb(main):015:0> service = ServiceBuilder.new()
                                  .provider(FacebookApi.class)
                                  .apiKey(apiKey)
                                  .apiSecret(apiSecret)
                                  .callback("http://localhost:3000/oauth_callback/")
                                  .build()

NoMethodError: undefined method `createService' for Class:Class
    from org/jruby/gen/InterfaceImpl1679303904.gen:13:in `createService'
    from (irb):15:in `evaluate'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1066:in `eval'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1409:in `loop'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1174:in `catch'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1174:in `catch'
    from /home/krunal/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.3@integration_hub/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/krunal/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.3@integration_hub/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/krunal/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.3@integration_hub/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `(root)'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `(root)'
irb(main):016:0>
```

https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java

https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/FacebookExample.java

Comment: Why does it not work?

Comment: This works perfect for java https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/FacebookExample.java

Comment: maybe it has to do with service being an OAuthService in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your issue is that you need to use `java_class` for your call to provider:

```
service = ServiceBuilder.new().provider(FacebookApi.java_class)
                              .api_key(api_key)
                              .api_secret(api_secret)
                              .callback("http://localhost:3000/oauth_callback/")
                              .build()
```

There's some more info [here](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby#referencing-a-javalangclass-object) about how to correctly reference `java.lang.Class` objects in JRuby.

All that said, I think that will fix your issue but maybe there's an easier way we can do this...

It looks like you're trying to create an oauth consumer here. Out of curiosity, why not use the Ruby oauth2 gem which works perfectly with JRuby?

You can read more about it here, but I think it would be a lot easier for you:
https://github.com/intridea/oauth2

Or for Facebook in particular, consider using Koala:
https://github.com/arsduo/koala

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_access_token)

profile = @graph.get_object("me")
friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
@graph.put_connections("me", "feed", :message => "I am writing on my wall!")
```

What's the rationale for trying to do this in Java from Ruby instead of leveraging the Ruby libraries available for this?

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure the java example you give is not printing out  `class org.scribe.oauth.OAuth20ServiceImpl`.  The reason being is that the java statement `new ServiceBuilder()` must return an instance of ServiceBuilder.

If you copied your code from the link you gave, then the java code that produces the output really is,

```
 OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                              .provider(FacebookApi.class)
                              .apiKey(apiKey)
                              .apiSecret(apiSecret)
                              .callback("http://www.example.com/oauth_callback/")
                              .build();
 System.out.println(">>>>>>>" + service.getClass());
```

Now it should be obvious why the ruby code is printing out something different, the ruby code should read,

```
 service = ServiceBuilder.new().provider(FacebookApi.class)
                               .apiKey(apiKey)
                               .apiSecret(apiSecret)
                               .callback("http://www.example.com/oauth_callback/")
                               .build()
 puts service.java_class
```

Comment: I had already tried this code. But when I am trying to access build method it's returns me errors. I think that method in built call some methods which belongs to OAuthService interface which causing this issue. https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/scribe/oauth/OAuthService.java

Comment: If you want help, post the actual code you use, and the error you get.  The more details the better.  The question you posted says nothing about an error, and does not contain the code in my answer.

Comment: Are you sure that code is producing the error, I see no createService method called.

Comment: build() method itself call the createService method.

Comment: the error you are getting is that jruby can't find the createService method, inside the build method, you can't get an undefined method exception